When I call an api, I get an acl error even though I created an acl
I wrote a code to get the answer from the api, which works correctly in Oracle 21. But in Oracle 11, even though I typed the acl codes, it still gives me the acl error.
Error:
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1339 ORA-29261: bad argument ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1284 ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130 ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
Code to get information from api:
declare
  vClob   clob;
  vDetectEMP number;
begin
  vClob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => 'http://localhost:8002',
                                              p_http_method => 'GET');
  APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_OR_TRUNCATE_COLLECTION(p_collection_name => 'API_RESPONSE');

  APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER(
        p_collection_name => 'API_RESPONSE',
        p_C001 => vClob);
end;

ACL:
DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
  ACL_ID    RAW(16);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to '*' and give APEX_030200
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_030200 does not have the privilege yet.

  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  -- Before checking the privilege, make sure that the ACL is valid
  -- (for example, does not contain stale references to dropped users).
  -- If it does, the following exception will be raised:
  --
  -- ORA-44416: Invalid ACL: Unresolved principal 'APEX_030200'
  -- ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDBZ", line ...
  --
  SELECT SYS_OP_R2O(extractValue(P.RES, '/Resource/XMLRef')) INTO ACL_ID
    FROM XDB.XDB$ACL A, PATH_VIEW P
   WHERE extractValue(P.RES, '/Resource/XMLRef') = REF(A) AND
         EQUALS_PATH(P.RES, ACL_PATH) = 1;

  DBMS_XDBZ.ValidateACL(ACL_ID);
   IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_200100',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_200100', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
    'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
    'APEX_200100', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
END;
/
COMMIT;



------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

declare
    acl_path  varchar2(4000);
begin
    select acl
      into acl_path
      from dba_network_acls
     where host = '*'
       and lower_port is null
       and upper_port is null;

    if dbms_network_acl_admin.check_privilege( acl_path, 'APEX_200100', 'connect' ) is null then
        dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege( acl_path,  'APEX_200100', true, 'connect' );
    end if;

exception
    when no_data_found then
        dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl(
            'power_users.xml',
            'acl that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
            'APEX_200100',
            true,
            'connect' );
        dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl( 'power_users.xml', '*' );
end;
/

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl => 'ANY_HOST_ACCESS.xml',description => 'POWER ACCESS USER',
    principal => 'JRUSER',is_grant => true,privilege => 'connect');
    
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl => 'ANY_HOST_ACCESS.xml',
    principal => 'JRUSER',is_grant => true,privilege => 'resolve');
    
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl => 'ANY_HOST_ACCESS.xml',
    principal => 'APEX_200100',is_grant => true,privilege => 'connect');
    
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl => 'ANY_HOST_ACCESS.xml',
    principal => 'APEX_200100',is_grant => true,privilege => 'resolve');
    
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl (
    acl => 'ANY_HOST_ACCESS.xml',host => '*',lower_port => 1,upper_port => 9999);
end;
/
commit;
/


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to '*' and give APEX_200100
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_200100 does not have the privilege yet.
  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;
  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_200100',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_200100', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
    'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
    'APEX_200100', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
END;
/
COMMIT;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to 'localhost' and give APEX_200100
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_200100 does not have the privilege yet.
  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = 'localhost' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;
   
  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_200100',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_200100', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;
  
EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to 'localhost'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('local-access-users.xml',
    'ACL that lets users to connect to localhost',
    'APEX_200100', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('local-access-users.xml','localhost');
END;
/
COMMIT;


Please help me if anyone knows
